# Jest - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I am using `jest:24.9.0` without any configuration, installed globally  from a create-react-app. Inside these files I am using es6 modules. There is no error when using `"test": "react-scripts test"`

However when I move to use `jest` with `"test": "jest --config jest.config.js",` I see the below error.

```
 FAIL  src/configuration/notifications.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /var/www/management/node/src/configuration/notifications.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import notifications from './notifications';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Jest doesn't support `ES6` module and hence throwing this error when you directly run the test with Jest. if you want to run like that then you have to add babel.

On the other side, when you run the test with `react-scripts` it uses babel behind the scene to Transpile the code.

> In newer version of jest, `babel-jest` is now automatically loaded by Jest and fully integrated

Hope this answer your question.

**Adding babel in jest.**

**Installation**

`babel-jest` is now automatically loaded by Jest and fully integrated. This step is only required if you are using babel-jest to transform TypeScript files.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-jest
```

**Usage**

In your `package.json` file make the following changes:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

**Create `.babelrc` configuration file**

Create a `babel.config.json` config in your project root and enable some `presets`.

To start, you can use the env preset, which enables transforms for ES2015+

```
npm install @babel/preset-env --save-dev
```

In order to enable the preset you have to define it in your `babel.config.json` file, like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Check for more details on [Babel official site](https://babeljs.io/en/setup?fireglass_rsn=true#installation)

Comment: How do you "add babel"?

Comment: NB that `.babelrc` doesn't work you have to name it `babel.config.json`

Comment: I had to `npm install regenerator-runtime` and also `import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'` at the top of my testfile

Comment: @GunarGessner is there a particular reason why .babelrc doesnt work?

Comment: @blu10 it just didn't work for me I guess

Comment: Solution doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Is the guidance here to modify package.json and ALSO add .babelrc? Or just one or the other?

Comment: When creating `.babelrc` file you should add at least `{}` or a json parse error will throw

Comment: The new version of Jest does support ES6, just upgrade it

Comment: I am using "jest": "^29.7.0", it does not support it, seems like. `import [...] as NgZone$1, ɵflushModuleScopingQueueAsMuchAsPossible } from '@angular/core'; SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` on the line `import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';`

Answer (score 20):

As answers above have described, Jest doesn't support ES6 modules. So, we need transform the code to a supported module type. We could use `babel-jest` or `ts-jest`. I recommend using `ts-jest` for simplicity.

**Step 1: installation:**

`npm i -D ts-jest @types/jest` or `yarn add --dev ts-jest @types/jest`

**Step 2: Configuration**

Option 1: create a jest configration file `jest.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
    },
};
```

Option 2: add jest  configration into `package.json`

```json
"jest": {
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
    }
}
```

**Step 3: Execute your script.** Everything should be all set now.

Comment: OP didn't try to make it work for typescript

Answer (score 4):

Since jest is not working with esmodules well, you need to add these configurations in `jest.config.js` to tell Jest to use commonJS builds instead

```js
moduleNameMapper : {
        '^react-dnd$': 'react-dnd/dist/cjs',
        '^react-dnd-html5-backend$': 'react-dnd-html5-backend/dist/cjs',
        '^dnd-core$': 'dnd-core/dist/cjs',
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

might also come from some imported library under `node_modules`, for example

```
...\node_modules\node-fetch\src\index.js:9
    import http from 'node:http';
    ^^^^^^
```

The trick for me was to use the `transformIgnorePatterns` option in jest config:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!' + 
        [
            'node-fetch',
            'fetch-blob',
            'data-uri-to-buffer',
            'jest-runtime',
            'formdata-polyfill'
        ].join('|') +
    ')',
],
```

Also see

[How to setup jest with node_modules that use es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60714101/how-to-setup-jest-with-node-modules-that-use-es6)

Comment: This worked for me when I got the error on an import statement for the node module `lucide-svelte`. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This one worked for me as well! But it might just be that `node-fetch` was only module I was importing from node_modules at the time.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Typescript with ECMAScript. The simplest solution is to use use [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest), a TypeScript preprocessor:

1. Install

```yaml
npm i -D ts-jest @types/jest
```

2. Run tests

```yaml
jest
```

[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-jest), [github](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest)

Answer (score 0):

I received this same error using react-scripts to run tests. I was able to resolve this issue by changing the line in package.json

```
"test": "react-scripts test",
```

to

```
"test": "NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules react-scripts test",
```

From the error message which provides the link that suggests this resolution:

```
Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add how I easily caused this issue for myself.. I freaking prevented myself from committing my jest.config.js file by including all *.js in my .gitignore. Every time my CI ran, I would get this error, because there was ***no version controlled jest.config.js in my repo***. Be careful out there folks! stay frosty.

Comment: What did you put in your jest.config.js to avoid the "Cannot use import statement outside a module" error?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has a long discussion in the source package with some alternative solutions https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/1174.

The solution that worked for me, using `Typescript`, `ES6` modules, and `jest` was using the package [ts-jest-mock-import-meta](https://github.com/ThomZz/ts-jest-mock-import-meta)