# Jest and Babel transpilation - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I struggle to use JEST for some cases where running the tests I get

Test suite failed to run

```
...node_modules\p-retry\index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import retry from 'retry';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

    > 1 | import pRetry from 'p-retry';
        | ^
      2 |
      3 | export function Retry(tries: number) {

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/common/Retry.ts:1:1)
```

Meanwhile my webpack build works nice with typescript and babel. I tried a lot of stuff (see below to get it working but no success so far - and haven't really been able to understand whats going on. From my pov - though the transpilation stuff is kind of a black area so far for me I tried to enable Jest to use ESModules andprovide code as such as well as tried providing commonJS module code.

So I am looking for alternative options and ways to investigate further. Particularly one thing strikes me as strange:
the Retry.ts file from the error is one of my files which imports the pRetry (a node_module written in ESModule style) which in its code does the import retry from 'retry' (another node-module written in commonJS style)from the very first line of the error.

So what seems to happen to me is that the pRetry is not transformed from it's ESModule Code (the source of pRetry starts with import retry from 'retry';) and just wrapped in some commonJS code instead if I interpret the syntax correctly.

So my next steps would likely be investigate what babel-jest really generates and check what's up there and try to deduct furhter. Does anybody know how to achieve this (especially understand what babel-jest generates) or has another idea?

Things I tried - all failed (sometimes slightly different errors)

1. using plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]  in babel.config.js
2. changing target and module in tsconfig.json to es5
3. introducing below in jest.config.ts transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/?!(p-retry)"]
4. using the following in jest.config.ts

> preset: "ts-jest",
> transform: {
> '^.+\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
> "^.+\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest"}

or alternatively with ts-jest for both or babel-jest for both

5. migrating from .babelrc file to babel.config.js as suggested by one post
6. AllowJS : true in tscfonfig.json  and transformIgnorePatterns in jest in combination
7. adding ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",{"regenerator": true}] to babel.config
8. Using

   preset: "ts-jest",
   testEnvironment: "node",
   transform: {"node_modules/p-retry/.+\.(j|t)sx?$": "ts-jest"},
   transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/(?!p-retry/.*)"]

in jest.config

9. using "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs" in babel.config
10. using @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs in babel.config
11. Applying the following steps as suggest by         [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756479/does-jest-support-es6-import-export#:~:text=Jest%20will%20enable%20compilation%20from,json%20.&text=If%20you%20don't%20want%20to%20pollute%20your%20project%20with%20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756479/does-jest-support-es6-import-export#:%7E:text=Jest%20will%20enable%20compilation%20from,json%20.&text=If%20you%20don%27t%20want%20to%20pollute%20your%20project%20with%20)

- Make sure you don't transform away import statements by setting
  transform: {} in config file
- Run node@^12.16.0 || >=13.2.0 with --experimental-vm-modules flag
- Run your test with jest-environment-node or jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen.

12. playing with testenvironment like jest-environment-node, node or jsdom in jest.config.ts

jest-config.ts:

```
const tsconfig = require("./tsconfig.json");
const moduleNameMapper = require("tsconfig-paths-jest")(tsconfig)

export default {
   collectCoverage: true,
   coverageDirectory: "analysis/coverage",
   coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"],
   collectCoverageFrom: ["src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts}"],
   coverageReporters: ["json", "lcov", "text", "clover"],
   coverageThreshold: {
      global: {
         branches: 0,
         functions: 0,
         lines: 0,
         statements: 0
      },
   },
   clearMocks: true,
   coverageProvider: "babel",
   moduleNameMapper,
   roots: ["<rootDir>/src/", "<rootDir>/test/"],
   testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-node', 
   testPathIgnorePatterns: [
      "\\\\node_modules\\\\"
   ],
   "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|ts|jsx)$": "babel-jest"
   }
};
```

babel.config.js:

```
    module.exports = {
   presets: ['@babel/preset-typescript',
      ['@babel/preset-env', {
         targets: { node: "current" }
      }],
      '@babel/preset-flow',

   ],
   plugins: [["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"], ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }], ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]]
}
```

Extract from package.json

```
"@babel/core": "^7.16.12",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.16.5",
"@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.16.8",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.16.10",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.4",
"@babel/preset-flow": "^7.16.7",
"@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.13.0",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.16.7",
"babel-jest": "^27.4.6",
"babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0",         
"jest": "^27.0.4",
"jest-config": "^27.4.5",
"jest-esm-transformer": "^1.0.0",
"ts-jest": "^27.1.3",
"tsconfig-paths-jest": "^0.0.1",
"core-js": "^3.20.0",
```

Comment: Just an additional note: Since with Jest 29 I again had the same issue from an error perspective but the previous solution didnt work and I in the past I kept having issues with jest I migrated to vitest. Api seems very much in line with jest and migration was a easy in my case. Maybe also an option for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I was close.

With a change of babel.config.ts by adding **esmodules: false** it is done :-)

```
module.exports = {
   presets: ['@babel/preset-typescript',
      ['@babel/preset-env', {
         targets: { esmodules: false, node: "current" }
      }],
      '@babel/preset-flow',
    
   ],
   plugins: [["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"], ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }], ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]]
}
```

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted but your solution doesn't work for me. Still trying to work out how to fix it.

Comment: same for me.... very annoying to haven't a global solution

Answer (score 2):

You can let Jest do not ignore transforming `p-retry` by adding this in your jest. config.js, it works for me.

```
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(p-retry)/)",
  ],
```

Comment: What if this library requires more libraries inside and that causes more errors?

Answer (score 2):

My solution with `"jest": "^28.1.0"`:

In `package.json`

1. under `devDependencies` add:

```
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.10"
```

2. and,

```
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$": "babel-jest"
  }
},
```

In `babel.config.json` add:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add specific module mappings as detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65250052/285549

This forces Jest to load the CommonJS version of the module since the tests are running in Node even though the eventual target is the browser.