# Jest: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module in React/Typescript project

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, babeljs, ts-jest

I am having an issue with Jest when it comes to testing certain components using Babel, Typescript, React, and Jest.

While testing a React/Typescript component I get `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

**Things I have tried**:

1. Using plugins for babel (see babel config below)
2. Using `ts-jest`
3. Tried `ts-jest` ESM Support from [**docs**](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support#:%7E:text=Version%3A%2028.0-,ESM%20Support,-To%20use%20ts)
4. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70883026/jest-and-babel-transpilation-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613492/how-to-resolve-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-in-jest), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781271/jest-wont-transform-the-module-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outsi) post that had similar issues

Here is the `jest.config.js`:

```
const ignores = ['/node_modules/'];

module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    roots: ['<rootDir>'],
    modulePaths: [
        "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    moduleDirectories: [
        "node_modules",
    ],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [...ignores],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
        '^.+\\.(gif|svg|ico)$': '<rootDir>/svgTransform.js',
    },
    testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.js?$',
    moduleFileExtensions: ['tsx', 'js', 'ts'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
        '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
      },
    clearMocks: true,
    // collectCoverage: true, // todo
    // coverageDirectory: "coverage",  // todo
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect', './src/tests/setup.js'],
    resolver: 'jest-webpack-resolver',
}
```

Here is the `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    // For transformation of TSX and other react related bable plugins
    presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env',  {
            targets: { esmodules: false, node: "current" }
         }],
        // Enabling Babel to understand TypeScript
        '@babel/preset-typescript', "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs', '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'],
}
```

Here is the Code-Trace of error:

[image: code-trace]

`package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "@unirep-social/frontend",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server",
        "start-local": "webpack-dev-server",
        "build": "webpack",
        "lint": "prettier .",
        "build:worker": "webpack --config webpack.worker.js",
        "postinstall": "link-module-alias && yarn copyCircuits",
        "copyCircuits": "node scripts/copy_circuits",
        "test": "jest --config ./jest.config.js",
        "test:watch": "jest --watch",
        "test:coverage": "jest --coverage"
    },
    "_moduleAliases": {
        "worker_threads": "./externals/worker_threads.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.18.6",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.15",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
        "@unirep/circuits": "git+https://github.com/Unirep/circuits.git#alpha",
        "@unirep/crypto": "git+https://github.com/Unirep/crypto.git",
        "@unirep/unirep": "git+https://github.com/Unirep/unirep.git#alpha",
        "@unirep/unirep-social": "git+https://github.com/Unirep/unirep-social.git#alpha",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
        "dateformat": "^4.5.1",
        "ethers": "^5.5.4",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
        "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.1.2",
        "keyv": "4.1.1",
        "markdown-it": "^12.3.2",
        "mobx": "^6.4.2",
        "mobx-react-lite": "^3.3.0",
        "n-readlines": "^1.0.1",
        "nanoid": "^4.0.0",
        "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.0.4",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-favicon": "^1.0.0",
        "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
        "react-jdenticon": "^0.0.9",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-router-hash-link": "^2.4.3",
        "snarkjs": "^0.3.59",
        "ts-jest": "^28.0.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.18.6",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
        "@cloudflare/kv-asset-handler": "^0.2.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "12.1.5",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.2.1",
        "@types/jest": "^28.1.4",
        "@types/keyv": "^3.1.2",
        "@types/markdown-it": "^12.2.3",
        "@types/n-readlines": "^1.0.2",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",
        "@types/shelljs": "^0.8.9",
        "assert": "^2.0.0",
        "babel-jest": "^28.1.2",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
        "buffer": "^6.0.3",
        "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
        "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
        "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.1",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
        "jest": "^28.1.2",
        "jest-axe": "^6.0.0",
        "jest-webpack-resolver": "^0.3.0",
        "link-module-alias": "^1.2.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.0",
        "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
        "prettier": "^2.6.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
        "sass": "^1.49.9",
        "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
        "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
        "ts-loader": "^9.2.8",
        "typescript": "^4.3.5",
        "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
        "webpack": "^5.70.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
    },
    "jestWebpackResolver": {
        "webpackConfig": "./webpack.config.js"
    },
    "prettier": {
        "tabWidth": 4,
        "singleQuote": true,
        "semi": false
    }
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
// const HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin = require('html-webpack-inline-source-plugin')
const path = require('path')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/index.tsx'],
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        // proxy: {
        //     '/api': {
        //         target: 'http://localhost:3000',
        //         router: () => 'http://localhost:3001',
        //     },
        // },
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json', '.scss'],
        fallback: {
            crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
            assert: require.resolve('assert/'),
            stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
            os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
            fs: false,
            dotenv: false,
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|ico)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            esModule: false,
                            limit: 8192,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                    'css-loader',
                    // Compiles Sass to CSS
                    'sass-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css)$/,
                // exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'public/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            inlineSource: '.(js|css)',
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'styles.css',
        }),
        // new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {},
            'process.argv': [],
            'process.versions': {},
            'process.versions.node': '"12"',
            process: {
                exit: '(() => {})',
                browser: true,
                versions: {},
                cwd: '(() => "")',
            },
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            Buffer: path.resolve(__dirname, 'externals', 'buffer.js'),
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\/keyv\//, (data) => {
            delete data.dependencies[0].critical
            return data
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\/maci\-crypto\//, (data) => {
            delete data.dependencies[0].critical
            return data
        }),
    ],
    optimization: {
        // minimizer: [
        //   `...`,
        //   new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
        // ],
    },
}
```

***What worked for me:***
Downgraded nanoid package to 3.3.4

Comment: You shouldn't need to use both Babel and TypeScript. Can you explain your webpack config (specifically whether you're using Babel or TypeScript)?

Comment: @NickMcCurdy Would you mind explaining why babel is not needed? Also, I just posted my webpack config file.

Comment: I meant that you don't need to use Babel together with TypeScript, because both can convert TypeScript to JavaScript. In this case, since you're building your webpack bundle with Babel, I'd recommend only using Babel with Jest. You can uninstall `ts-jest`, which should hopefully speed up and simplify your test setup.

Comment: Ah, I see. So what would you recommend the preset in the jest file be? The test time was getting lengthy and this is probably why. @NickMcCurdy

Comment: Are you using TypeScript in this project? I noticed the `.js` extension.

Comment: @NickMcCurdy Yes, I mentioned that above.

Comment: Note: Fixed by downgrading nanoid package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP posted it as a comment but, he fixed it by downgrading the `nanoid` package from v4.0.0

I was facing the same issue and downgrading to the previous stable version `3.3.4` worked for me. Here is how I did it:

`npm i nanoid@3.3.4`

Thanks OP!

Comment: Also, made an edit to the original post about downgrading nanoid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72933087/jest-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-in-react-typescr/73795371#:~:text=What%20worked%20for%20me%3A%20Downgraded%20nanoid%20package%20to%203.3.4

Comment: Did not work for me, I'm on nanoid@3.3.4! Same problem

Comment: @PeterStjernholmMeldgaard what node version do you have