# Jest report "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" for file in node_modules

Tags: node.js, jestjs, babel-jest

I am writing a jest test to test a nodejs component. That component used a module called "node:http" from ***node_modules***, and when I run `npm test`, it shows the following error:

```
By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    ..../Server/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:9
    import http from 'node:http';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | 'use strict'
      2 |
    > 3 | import fetch from "node-fetch";
```

I have already set up my environment via following [Jest - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59879689/jest-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module). However, it seems the setting is only for use import in jest, not the case that modules in *node_modules*.

I also have added the following settings for transformIgnorePatterns, but it does not work.

```
"jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!node:http)"
    ]
  },
```

Could anyone please inform me how to resolve the issue? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Did you try the suggestions Jest gave you? What was the result of each?

Comment: @CherryDT How stupid I am! Somehow, I did not try the first suggestion, after you remind me, I tried the first one with "NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest", now, everything works like a charm. Thank you so much.