# jest "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: typescript, ts-jest, babel-jest

**Tried following the answers in [58613492](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613492/how-to-resolve-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-in-jest),[59879689](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59879689/jest-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module) and [61781271](https://61781271)**

having the following error with jest :

```
  SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import { Lambda, SecretsManager, config as awsConfig } from 'aws-sdk';
    > 2 | import axios from 'axios';
```

As you can see, it only complains about the second line (..?)

using `node` v14.19.3

my `tsconfig.ts`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true ,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true ,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "lib": ["ES2020.Promise"],
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true ,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

my `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    preset: "ts-jest",
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$": "ts-jest",
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
    },
    testEnvironment: "node",
    testTimeout: 60000,
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ["dist/*"],
};
```

my `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        '@babel/preset-typescript',
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                targets: { esmodules: false, node: 'current' },
            },
        ],
        '@babel/preset-flow',
    ],
    plugins: [
        ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs'],
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
    ],
};
```

`package.json`

```
{
    "name": "device-job-sender",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "src/handlers/job-sender-handler.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest --detectOpenHandles",
        "deploy:local": "sls deploy --stage local",
        "start:local": "docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d && npm run deploy:local",
        "deploy": "./.circleci/deploy.sh",
        "prettify": "prettier \"{src,test,scripts}/**/*.{js,ts}\" --write"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/vnatures/device-job-sender.git"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/vnatures/device-job-sender/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/vnatures/device-job-sender#readme",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.5",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.14.5",
        "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.79",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
        "@types/redis": "^2.8.29",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^6.2.12",
        "husky": "^7.0.1",
        "jest": "^26.6.3",
        "ts-jest": "^26.5.6",
        "ts-loader": "^8.1.0",
        "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
        "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
        "typescript": "^4.2.3",
        "webpack": "^4.44.1",
        "webpack-node-externals": "^2.5.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/aws-iot-device-sdk": "^2.2.3",
        "@vnatures/logger": "^2.0.1",
        "@vnatures/secrets-manager": "^2.0.2",
        "axios": "^1.3.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: what about your package.json?

Comment: updating the question, will add package.json

Comment: try adding `type: module` to your package.json

Comment: tried, same error ..

Comment: try adding this to your `jest.config.ts` `transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(axios)/)']` , hopefully that will be it, let me know if so :)

Comment: unfortunately got the same error